# How to get all businsess addresses from Google Maps by providing companies name

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geolocation

I have the requirement but i dont know which Google Service could fit this. I have a company name. Lets say "General Motors" or "IBM". I want to get all Google Locations where the Company Name is for example "IBM".

Is this possible? Which service would be the best for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Google place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

It's easy, and you can set keyword option as you wish.

[official demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search)

hope this help.